# How to make an ImageView randomly move across the screen without going off screen?

Tags: java, android, xml, animation, imageview

I have an ImageView that I want to slowly move across the screen in a random direction each time but when it hits the edge of the screen, I want it to bounce off in another direction, sort of like [the old DVD player screen saver](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DXQ9sCpRwkw). Is this possible without building a physics world and if so, could you please provide an example?

EDIT: I haven't implemented any code yet because I haven't found a method that fits all of the criteria but I have implemented this:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
int screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels; getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
```

but the only two methods I can think of for achieving the motion I want are the ViewPropertyAnimator or translating the X and Y with integers directly which I can't think of how I could incorporate it randomly and within the screen size.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use View Animation, you can check some docs in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html

Comment: But how would you set boundaries for the animation? I've read through all of the guides for view and object animation and I can't find anything that allows you to not only restrict the animation zone but also have the view interact with the boundaries. The only way I could use view animation is if I predetermined the X and Y start and end for each view and that isn't random like I asked in my question.